# DisplayFor in razor with nullable decimal changes format

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc, asp.net-mvc-4, razor

I have a property on my model like:

```
[DisplayFormat(DataFormatString = "{0:P0}")]
public decimal ? Rate {
    get;
    set;
}
```

In my razor view i have:

```
<span class="large bold">- @Html.DisplayFor(x => x.Rate)</span>
```

The problem is this: the number i need to show is `28.71` (decimal?) 
if the `DisplayFor` is with `x => x.Rate` then the view shows `2.871` but if the `DisplayFor` is with `x => x.Rate.Value` then the view shows the correct number `28.71`.

What's happening here??

Answer (score 2, accepted):

From [MSDN](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/dwhawy9k(v=vs.110).aspx#PFormatString):

> The percent ("P") format specifier multiplies a number by 100 and
>   converts it to a string that represents a percentage. The precision
>   specifier indicates the desired number of decimal places.

The `{0:P0}` format will display your decimal number (28.71) as 28.71 * 100 = `2,871 %` (assuming you're using the en-US culture).

If you just want to add the percentage sign to the number and display it, use this:

```
[DisplayFormat(DataFormatString = "{0} %")]
```

Comment: Yes... but this doesn't answer my question.. the number `28.71` is not the same number that `2,871` and the difference between `Rate` and `Rate.Value` giving different results doesn't have any sense

Comment: It does make sense. The `DisplayFormat` attribute only works with the `Rate` property. When you use  `Rate.Value`, the `DisplayFormat` doesn't work anymore, that's why you just get 28.71. And, I already explained why you get  `2,871` (28.71 * 100 = 2,871).

Answer (score 0):

```
DataFormatString = "{0:C0}"
```

That should do the job. I think P0 is used for percentage.

Comment: But i want to use it as a percentage